# My navigation text wont go all the way to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my website :  oxfordmakespace.com

My issue is I cannot get the navigation bar to move all the way to the left, I have searched for padding or margins that may be doing it and cannot find them.

The navbar is modified with the .nav attribute

Here is my CSS

```
             body {
             background-color: #999;
             background-size: 100% ;
             background-repeat: repeat;
             /* background-image: url(/Images/swanon.jpg); */
             font-size: 87.5%;
             font-family:Arial, serif-sans;

             }

    .body {
    /*text-align: left;*/

    clear: both;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 0%;
    width: 80%;

    }

    div {
    background: #1000;
    }


    .mainheader img {
    margin: 0% auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 ;
    }


    .maincontent {
    line-height: 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;

    }


    .Content {
    background: #855; /*red -----------*/
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    }

    .topcontent {
    background: #777; /* grey -------------------*/
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    }

    .bottomcontent {
    background: #777;  /* grey -------------------*/
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;

    }




    .post-info {

    Font-style: italic;
    color: #222;
    fon-size: 85%;
    }



    .top-sidebar {
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    width: 29.5%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #255;  /* cyan -------------------*/
    }

    .middle-sidebar {
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    width: 29.5%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #254;   /* cyan green -------------------*/

    }

    .bottom-sidebar {
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    width: 29.5%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #253;  /* green -------------------*/

    }


    .mainfooter {
    margin-top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;


    }

    .mainfooter p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 92%;
    padding-left: 0.8% ;
    padding-right: 0.2%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;

    }

    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .maincontent a {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .maincontent a:link, a:visited {
    color: orange;
    }

    .maincontent a:hover, a:active {
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    }


    /* navbar desktop */
    .nav {

    background-color: #612;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;

    }
    .nav li {

    float: left;
    display: inline;

    }
    .nav a, .nav a:link, .nav a:visited {

    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    }
    .nav a:active, a:visited {
    color: Black;
    }
    .nav .current a {
    background: #499;
    color: black; /*this changes the desktop view current link*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .nav a:hover, .nav a:active, .nav .active a:link, .nav .active a:visited {
    background: #253;


    }




    /*<!----------------------------------------------------------------->*/

    .nav2 ul {
    padding-right: 5%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .nav2 li {

    float: right;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;

    /*margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;*/
    }
    .nav2 a, .nav a:link, .nav a:visited {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    }
    .nav2 a:active, a:visited {
    color: Black;
    }
    .nav2 .current a {
    background: #499;
    color: black; /*this changes the desktop view current link*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .nav2 a:hover, .nav a:active, .nav .active a:link, .nav .active a:visited {
    background: #253;

    }






    @media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px), (orientation : portrait) 
    {



    .body {
    width: 95%;
    font-size: 100%;
    }



    .mainheader img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }


    .mainheader nav {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 120px;

    }


    .mainheader nav ul {
    padding-left: 0%;
    }

    .mainheader nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

    }

    .mainheader nav a, .mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
    float: none;
    color: Black;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    }


    .mainheader nav a:hover, .mainheader nav a:active, .mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader             nav .active a:visited {
    background: #199;  /*<!---------------------------nav button color-->*/

    }



    .mainheader nav ul li a {   

    }

    .maincontent {
        line-height: 15px;

    }


    .Content {
    background: #215; /*blue-----------*/
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    }

    .post-info {
    display: none;

    }

    .topcontent, .bottomcontent {
    background: #777; /* grey -------------------*/
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    }



    .top-sidebar, .middle-sidebar, .bottom-sidebar {
    padding: 1% 5%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 90%;
    float: left;

    }


    /*NAVBAR--------------------------*/


    .nav {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 40px;
        background-color: #999;
        margin: 0px 0;
        }

    a {
    color: Black;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;

    }


    .nav ul {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%; /*this controls the displayed word padding*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; /*physical position of box holding links*/
        left: 46.2%; /*physical position of box holding links*/
        border: solid 0px #aaa;
        background: #fff url(Images/topright.png) no-repeat ; /*background color for links*/
        background-size: 15% 75%; /*changes for image*/
        background-position: 90% 50%;
        border-radius: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
         -o-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    }
    .nav li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
        display: none; /* hide all <li> items */
        margin: 0;
    }
    .nav .current {
        padding: 0 0 10px 0 ;
        Background: none;
        pointer-events: none; /*allows you to click on the menu usinga touch screen and not make the     page load*/
        display: block; /* show only current <li> item */
    }

    .nav .current a {
        background: none;
        color: Black; /* changes current links color when not active*/
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------*/

    .nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3% 5% 3% 10%;
        text-align: Left;   
        color: black; /*changes every text item in mobile menu*/
        font-size: 150%;
        font-style: Arial,serif-sans;
    }

    .nav a:link {

    color: black;
    }

    .nav a:hover { /*changes the moused over or selected link in nav bar*/

        border-radius: 5px;
        color: black;
        background: lightgreen;

    }

    /*-------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* on nav hover */
    .nav ul:hover {
        background-image: none;/*hides the background image when the navbar exands to stop it     stretching*/
    }
    .nav ul:hover li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 5px; /*space between each menu item*/

    }

    /*-------------------------------------------------------*/

    } /*media query end--------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 3):

it's a `padding` issue on `.nav > ul`

```
.nav ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0; //reset default padding
}
```

Your `ul` elements are collapsed as well. You need to clear your floated elements with a clearfix or `overflow: hidden;`. This works kind of by accident, but you really should correct these issues. The following should be added:

```
.nav{
    background-color: #612;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden; //add to correct floats
}

.nav ul { //for both nav menus
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0; //reset default padding
   overflow: hidden; //add to correct floats
   float: left; // which will float both left, we will override the second since it has an identifier
}

.nav2{
   float: right;
}

.nav2 ul{
   padding-right: 5%;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   float: none; //add to clear the float from the other ul
}
```

Comment: @JaredReabow no problem. I added some more code you should add to correct your floats

Comment: @JaredReabow and if this solved your issue can you check it off as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

ul's automatically tend to have both margins and padding
add

```
padding: 0;
```

to your list and it should go all the way to the left